# polydev Polymer Cannot read property '_bound' of null

Tags: polymer

Is there a problem with Polydev?

I develop an app using Polymer, and since Friday I have this error "Cannot read property '_bound' of null" for every paper-button action. 
Before the error didn't popped up, and the actions worked fine.

Comment: can you please add some code as well as that would make it easy to debug. Thanks

Comment: it's not a code problem. The paper-buttons work fine on Safari and Firefox but for Chrome every time I click a paper-button the error appears in the console.

Comment: I will disable polydev  https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polydev/issues/23

Comment: I was facing the same problem with iron-flex-layout today. However when i pushed my code to github and checked the published version it works fine. Maybe its a problem with the chrome polydev.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will do the same

Comment: Uninstalling polymer devtools  extension has solved my problem